# FFmpeg's trim command not honoring start value? Video playing from beginning through to trims' end value

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've got a rather weird problem. I can't seem to get ffmpeg's `trim` command to actually honor the `start` time and drop the frames before it.

For instance, given the command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i myvid.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]trim=start=15:end=25;[0:a]atrim=start=15:end=25' out.mp4
```

I would expect that `out.mp4` contains the a 10 second clip of `myvid.mp4` that starts at the 15th second and plays till the 25th. However, what I actually get is a 25 second video with a single static frame for the first 15 seconds, and then the normal video for the next 10. Any clues what's going on here?

Here's an example clip to demonstrate the effect:

http://gfycat.com/FearfulDigitalIndianskimmer

Edit:

Thinking that this was perhaps a quirk in the Windows version of ffmpeg. I spun up an instance of Ubuntu so I could test the syntax there as well. For what it's worth, the same problem happens on linux.

Comment: You should always show the complete console output from your command. Please paste the output as text instead of a screenshot as Windows users tend to do.